# Observable not reacting to blocking collection changed on different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive, observer-pattern

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var watcher = new SNotifier(DumpToConsole);
        watcher.StartQueue();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DumpToConsole(IList<Timestamped<int>> currentCol)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("buffer time elapsed, current collection contents is: {0} items.", currentCol.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("holder has: {0}", currentCol.Count);
    }
}
```

the SNotifier:

```
public class SNotifier
{
    private BlockingCollection<int> _holderQueue;
    private readonly Action<IList<Timestamped<int>>> _dumpAction;

    public SNotifier(Action<IList<Timestamped<int>>> dumpAction)
    {
        PopulateListWithStartValues();
        _dumpAction = dumpAction;
    }

    public void StartQueue()
    {
        PopulateQueueOnDiffThread();

        var observableCollection = _holderQueue.ToObservable();

        var myCollectionTimestamped = observableCollection.Timestamp();
        var bufferedTimestampedCollection = myCollectionTimestamped.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        using (bufferedTimestampedCollection.Subscribe(_dumpAction))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("started observing collection");
        }
    }

    private void PopulateQueueOnDiffThread()
    {
        Action addToCollectionAction = AddToCollection;
        var t = new TaskFactory();
        t.StartNew(addToCollectionAction);

    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> GetInitialElements()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var items = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            items.Add(random.Next(1, 10));

        return items;
    }

    private void AddToCollection()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var newElement = new Random().Next(1, 10);
            _holderQueue.Add(newElement);
            Console.WriteLine("added {0}", newElement);
            Console.WriteLine("holder has: {0}", _holderQueue.Count);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void PopulateListWithStartValues()
    {
        _holderQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
        var elements = GetInitialElements();
        foreach (var i in elements)
            _holderQueue.Add(i);
    }
}
```

I need to run the DumpToConsole() method to show the collection count every **3 seconds**, while this collection is having its contents changed on another thread. My problem is that DumpToConsole() is **only called once**. Why is that?! Ive spent already the entire day on this. Since I've subscribed with my dump method  to the observable, it should "observe" the collection changes and re-call the DumpToConsole() method every 3 seconds; thats what I need.

Ideas? Thanks

(P.S. the action passed to the SNotifier class is my way of removing console related stuff in the SNotifier, i'll need to refactor that better, it can be ignored as it has nothing to do with the problem itself)

Answer (score 7):

You are calling `ToObservable()` on your `BlockingCollection<int>`. This extension method simply takes the `IEnumerable<int>` interface on the collection and converts it to an `IObservable<int>`. This has the effect of getting a list of the contents of the collection *at the point of subscription* and dumping them out via an Observable stream.

It will not continue to enumerate items as they are added.

Use [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186(v=vs.110).aspx) in front of `ToObservable()` would address this.

However, caution is required as this will also remove items from the collection though, which might not be desirable.

If this is acceptable, you may want to publish the resulting observable in the case of multiple subscribers to avoid wreaking havoc.

If you are just adding, you could consider turning the whole thing around - use a Subject to back an "Add" method and have one subscriber fill a List (or BlockingCollection if you need that) to track the collection, and a second subscriber can then report on progress.

Another approach would be to use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) and subscribe to its events.

In the last two suggestions, you would need to make your "Add" thread-safe since neither `Subject<T>` nor `ObservableCollection<T>` are thread-safe themselves.

#### Addendum

Brandon's comment that you are disposing the subscription in `StartQueue` made me realise another problem - `StartQueue` will never return! This is because a call to `Subscribe` made on a `ToObservable()` conversion of an `IEnumerable` will not return until the enumeration has completed - it also therefore holds up disposal (since the `IDisposable` is the return value of `Subscribe`) which is why I didn't notice the `using` @Brandon pointed out either!

With the above two points, you need to make the following additional changes. First, remove the `using` statement around the subscription, the implicit disposal would cancel the subscription. When we solve the blocking Subscribe call this would then cause the subscription to be immediately cancelled. You should preserve the `IDisposable` handle if you do need to explicitly unsubscribe at some point.

Second, add a call to `SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default)` immediately after the `ToObservable()` to prevent the `Subscribe` call blocking.

Comment: OP is also immediately disposing the subscription (via `using`).

Comment: @Brandon - Good spot; made me realise an insidious additional issue (see the Addendum).

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions, they are rich in details, therefore a bit  overwhelming, causing me some confusion as to what to choose for my requirement; here's what I need, please let me know which of your suggestion would apply best: i need a collection of integers, where items will be added by multiple threads; every 10min the collection is "flushed" (all items are written on disk, collection is emptied). So, the keywords here are: multithreaded collection, observe it and every 10min flush its items. Which one of your suggestions works best for this?

Comment: also, does the .GetConsumingEnumerable() simply remove all items from the observed collection, each time it is called? My requirement is to remove the items from the collection ONLY when the time has elapsed. Can you please clarify this detail. Thank you in advance