# How can I make an IObservable from a queue, so that the sequence doesn't end when the queue is empty?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm working on something that uses Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx) and I want to have a sequence that takes its input from a queue (or similar).

I've tried doing this:

```
    static readonly Queue<DeviceTransaction> TransactionQueue = new Queue<DeviceTransaction>();
    //...
    var observableTransactionSource = TransactionQueue.ToObservable();
    //...
    observableTransactionSource.Subscribe(transactionObserver);
```

It works up to a point, but the sequence completes when the queue is empty. I don't want an empty queue to end the sequence. Empty doesn't mean ended, it just means 'no more at the moment'.

Is there a way to stop the sequence completing when the queue is empty, or should I be thinking about the whole problem in a different way?

Comment: You'll need to be using a different type of collection than a `Queue`, one that fires an event when an item is added, such as an `ObservableCollection` or that lets you wait until an item is added, such as a `BlockingCollection` (although in your case you want it to be asynchronous, not synchronous, so a BC wouldn't be ideal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `ToObservable()` is fraught with problems, as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988120/observable-not-reacting-to-blocking-collection-changed-on-different-thread/27989395#27989395) it is just going to use the `IEnumerable<T>` and consume a snapshot of the queue.

In this case, you are probably far better off using a `Subject<T>` to back your events. Since the Rx grammar specifies you must serialize delivery of events, it *already* has queueing semantics. Just call `OnNext<T>` on the subject to post events.

If you need to ensure events aren't missed by subscription occurring after events have been posted, use a `ReplaySubject<T>`.

If using a subject concerns you, then you might want to review [this blog post](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx). To summarise that, your use of a queue suggests it is fine to use a subject here, but you might want to consider if you can use a conversion method like `Observable.FromEvent`.

Comment: Thanks James, lots of good leads there to read up on and try out. I'm actually not tied to the idea of a queue since some of the time the user of my component will want to block on the transaction (other times not). I was starting to come around to the idea that I might need to make a Subject. I'll read the link you provided and post back on how I eventually did it...

Comment: Excellent blog post by Dave Sexton... This nails it: "When should I use a subject?  To generate a hot observable imperatively and statefully, without any direct external source." I believe that clarifies my situation quite a lot.

Comment: In the end, I made a class that raises an event every time a new item is created and used `Observable.FromEventPattern()` to observe that. It seems to work, but I'm not sure if that will guarantee serialization; what would happen if multiple threads are producing new items (the event would therefore potentially fire on multiple threads) ?

Comment: If your events can be raised concurrently, that would indeed cause problems. There was a deliberate design decision made to improve performance not to add checks for concurrent calls to `OnNext` all over the place. Have a read up on [`Subject.Synchronize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229816(v=vs.103)) - also called [`serialize`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/serialize.html) on other platforms - to see how to safely use a subject in this case - or consider using some other thread safety mechanism in your event.

Comment: that comment appears to be at odds with your original answer, which says "the Rx grammar enforces serialized delivery of events". I certainly rely on that behaviour and indeed it is my primary motivation for using Rx. Perhaps I am misunderstaning?

Comment: Yes, my use of "enforce" is misleading. The grammar lays out the rules, the code doesn't enforce it. i.e. The rules say you must serialize, but it's up to you to do that. Rx provides the Synchronize method to help you. Updated my answer.

Comment: That is rather unfortunate. I've always seen it as the raison detre of Rx that it enforces its own grammar, including the serialization part. Some of my code is probably going to start failing in mysterious ways if that assumption no longer holds.

Comment: Well, as that performance enhancement was made around version 1.1 of RX circa 2012, it's been an invalid assumption for quite some time... having worked on some pretty large and complex RX heavy solutions without running into problems, I can give you some comfort that it's a very manageable situation. Remember, it's only at the entry points to the RX pipelines you'll have to get it right - and if you've factored your code sensibly, you shouldn't have many places in your code to look at for this.

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement. It is something I will have to be mindful of. My first project using Rx was laid down in 2015 so if I were going to run into problems, then most likely I already would have done so.